# Does anyone know how can i setup live inline output in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I need to setup live code compiler for javascript. I had seen many videos on youtube where the output of the code is printed in the same line of the code.

Example:

const a = 5;
const b = 10;

console.log(a + b) {output will print here as "15"}

If anyone know, Please help me.

I searched for many extensions on VS code but didi not find that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for QuokkaJS

https://quokkajs.com/